# I want to access the key property of the li element in my function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

so i have *li* elements with key property and I want to access the their key property in my function

I am trying something like this

```
deleteTask(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(event.currentTarget.parentElement.key.value);   
}
```

but i dont know how to access the key property

```
const temp1 = temp.map( (x,i) => {
           return(
               <li key={i}>{x}
                   <button onClick={this.editTask.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
                   <button onClick=
                   {this.deleteTask.bind(this)}>Delete</button>
               </li>
           )
       })
```

I am getting the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
>   Task.deleteTask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it by passing into function

```
<li key={i}>{x}
         <button onClick={this.editTask.bind(this,i)}>Edit</button>
         <button onClick={this.deleteTask.bind(this,i)}>Delete</button>
</li>

deleteTask(key){
    event.preventDefault();
    //You can access key here
       console.log(key)  
    //this works perfectly fine
}
```

Comment: when i use this ``` deleteTask(key){
    //event.preventDefault();

    console.log(key);
    //console.log(this.props.key);  
}``` it works fine. but when i use ```deleteTask(event,key){
    event.preventDefault();

    console.log(key);
    //console.log(this.props.key);

    
}
``` it gives error that TypeError: event.preventDefault is not a function

Answer (score 0):

How about add a data-key to the <li>:

```
const temp1 = temp.map( (x,i) => {
       return(
           <li key={i} data-key={i}>{x}
               <button onClick={this.editTask.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
               <button onClick=
               {this.deleteTask.bind(this)}>Delete</button>
           </li>
       )
   })
```

Then:

```
console.log(event.currentTarget.parentElement.dataset['key']);
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: ['a','b','c']
    };
    this.deleteItem = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
  }
  
  deleteItem(index) {
    console.log('Deleting task:' + index);
    this.setState((prevState) => {
      const aux = Array.from(prevState.items);
      aux.splice(index,1);
      return ({
        ...prevState,
        items: aux
      });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    const listItems = this.state.items.map((item,index) => { 
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
          <li key={index}>{item + ' '}
            <button onClick={() => this.deleteItem(index)}>X</button>
          </li>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
      }
    );
    return(
      <ul>
        {listItems}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```